# Allocate values from different options - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that contains numerous `Places` at recurring time periods. These `Places` are beginning and finishing in random fashion. For each time period, I want to assign each unique place to a `Group`. The central rules in doing this are:

1) Each `Group` can hold no more than 3 unique `Places` **at any one time**

2) Unique `Places` should be evenly distributed across each `Group`

I've taken a very small subsection of the `df`. There are 7 unique values (but no more than 5 occuring at any one time) and 2 `Groups` to choose from. But in practice, the `df` could contain up to 50 unique values in total that finish and end and varying time periods that will be distributed across a maximum of 6 Groups.

To understand how many `Places` are currently occuring I've included a `Total`, which is based on if the `Place` appears again.

The `df` contains all available `Groups` for each unique `Place` at each `Period`. Places `Golf` and `Club` will finish but we assume all other places are continued as they appear later in the `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Period' : [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6],  
    'Place' : ['CLUB','CLUB','CLUB','HOME','HOME','AWAY','AWAY','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','GOLF','GOLF','CLUB','CLUB','POOL','POOL','HOME','HOME','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','POOL','POOL','TENNIS','TENNIS'],                                
    'Total' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5],                            
    'Available Group' : ['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1'],                           
    })
```

The main issue that's causing me trouble is `Places` appear/exist dynamically. In that, they finish and new ones begin in a random fashion. So assigning and distributing the **current** unique `Places` needs to account for this concept

Attempt:

```
def AssignPlace(df):
        uniquePlaces = df['Place'].unique()
        G3 = dict(zip(uniquePlaces, np.arange(len(uniquePlaces)) // 3 + 1))
        df['Assigned Group'] = df['Place'].map(G3)
        return df

df = df.groupby('Available Group', sort=False).apply(AssignPlace)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Period','Place'])
```

Out:

```
    Period   Place  Total Available Group  Assigned Group
0   1       CLUB    1      1               1             
1   2       CLUB    1      2               1             
3   2       HOME    2      2               1             
5   2       AWAY    3      2               1             
7   3       WORK    4      2               2             
9   3       AWAY    4      1               1             
11  3       GOLF    5      1               2  #GOLF FINISHES SO 4 OCCURING FROM NEXT ROW            
13  4       CLUB    4      2               1  #CLUB FINISHES BUT POOL STARTS SO STILL 4 OCCURING FROM NEXT ROW           
15  4       POOL    4      2               2             
17  4       HOME    4      2               1             
19  5       WORK    4      2               2             
21  5       AWAY    4      1               1             
23  5       POOL    4      1               2             
25  6       TENNIS  5      2               3  #Signifies issue
```

The last row displays the start of the issue. The assigned group measures this place correctly as the 7th unique value but it doesn't account for *current* unique values. As `Club` and `Golf` finish, they are only 5 current unqiue values and 2 available groups. But it's returning `Group 3`. So each new unique value will continue to be counted, rather than account for currently occuring unique values.

Intended Output, `TENNIS` Assigned Group is now `1`, instead of `3`:

```
    Period   Place  Total Available Group  Assigned Group
0   1       CLUB    1      1               1             
1   2       CLUB    1      2               1             
3   2       HOME    2      2               1             
5   2       AWAY    3      2               1             
7   3       WORK    4      2               2             
9   3       AWAY    4      1               1             
11  3       GOLF    5      1               2             
13  4       CLUB    4      2               1             
15  4       POOL    4      2               2             
17  4       HOME    4      2               1             
19  5       WORK    4      2               2             
21  5       AWAY    4      1               1             
23  5       POOL    4      1               2             
25  6       TENNIS  5      2               1
```

Comment: Sorry @jezrael. It's a little more complex than that. I'll add some more context

Comment: So the example df contains 5 unique values in Place. My actual df could contain up to 50 unique Places that are starting and ending at random time periods. So the Places a Group is currently holding will be in constant change

Comment: So if change `df = df.groupby('Group', sort=False).apply(AssignPlace)` - grouping by `Group` it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my try.
Explanation are on code comment, if not enough leave me a comment here

**NOTE**: I have added 5 dummy rows at bottom to simulate that those places will appear latter in df. So please ignore rows with period=0

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Period' : [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,0,0,0,0,0],  
    'Place' : ['CLUB','CLUB','CLUB','HOME','HOME','AWAY','AWAY','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','GOLF','GOLF','CLUB','CLUB','POOL','POOL','HOME','HOME','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','POOL','POOL','TENNIS','TENNIS', "AWAY","HOME","POOL","WORK", "TENNIS"],                                
#     'Total' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,0,0,0,0,0],                            
#     'Available Group' : ['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1',0,0,0,0,0],                           
    })

# df to store all unique places
uniquePlaces = pd.DataFrame(df["Place"].unique(), columns=["Place"])
# Start stores index of df where the place appears 1st
uniquePlaces["Start"] = -1
# End stores index of df where the place appears last 
uniquePlaces["End"] = -1

## adds new column "Place Label" which is label encoded value for a place
## "Place Label" may not be necessary but it may improve performance when looking up and merging
## this function also updates Start and End of current label in group
def assign_place_label(group):
    label=uniquePlaces[uniquePlaces["Place"]==group.name].index[0]
    group["Place Label"] = label
    uniquePlaces.loc[label, "Start"] = group.index.min()
    uniquePlaces.loc[label, "End"] = group.index.max()
    return group

## based on Start and End of each place assign index to each place
## when a freed the index is reused to new place appearing after that
def get_dynamic_group(up):
    up["Index"] = 0
    up["Freed"] = False
    max_ind=0
    free_indx = []
    for i in range(len(up)):
        ind_freed = up.index[(up["End"]<up.iloc[i]["Start"]) & (~up["Freed"])]
        free = list(up.loc[ind_freed, "Index"])
        free_indx += free

        up.loc[ind_freed, "Freed"] = True


        if len(free_indx)>0:
            m = min(free_indx)
            up.loc[i, "Index"] = m
            free_indx.remove(m)

        else:
            up.loc[i, "Index"] = max_ind
            max_ind+=1

    up["Group"] = up["Index"]//3+1

    return up  

df2 = df.groupby("Place").apply(assign_place_label)
uniquePlaces = get_dynamic_group(uniquePlaces)

display(uniquePlaces)

df3 = df2[df2.Period!=0].drop_duplicates(subset = ['Period','Place'])
result = df3.merge(uniquePlaces[["Group"]], how="left", left_on="Place Label", 
                   right_index=True, sort=False)
display(result)
```

**Output**

```
    Period  Place   Place Label Group
0   1   CLUB    0   1
1   2   CLUB    0   1
3   2   HOME    1   1
5   2   AWAY    2   1
7   3   WORK    3   2
9   3   AWAY    2   1
11  3   GOLF    4   2
13  4   CLUB    0   1
15  4   POOL    5   2
17  4   HOME    1   1
19  5   WORK    3   2
21  5   AWAY    2   1
23  5   POOL    5   2
25  6   TENNIS  6   1
```

Comment: Thanks @Dev Khadka. It works well up to a certain point for my actual dataset. The point it breaks down is when I have 3 Groups to pick from to hold 8 unique places. This works great until 5 finish, which leaves 3 unique places occuring. They are distributed across these 3 Groups (so one each), which is great. But the next unique value that appears (which would be the 4th unique value occuring) gets assigned to a 4th Group. But we only have 3 available Groups to pick from. The next unique value also gets assigned to Group 4. But the following unique values get distributed across Groups 1-3.

Comment: you can debug the issue by lookin at ```display(uniquePlaces)``` after ```uniquePlaces = get_dynamic_group(uniquePlaces)```. One logic of assigning group is item will take same group from when it starts to end. Only new items will be assigned freed space. So if a place is assigned group 3 and it also appears on last row it will still be assigned group3 even if at last row it is the only place

Comment: Ok. I've done some different sceneraios and it appears that a new Group is added during these periods where the unique places drops and new items aren't being assigned free space.

Comment: @jonboy I think I found the issue, when reassigning it was not taking min available value I have corrected in above answer by adding these lines ```m = min(free_indx)
            up.loc[i, "Index"] = m
            free_indx.remove(m)```

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to debug. It's works great up until a point again. I'm not sure if it's another edge case. Following on from last time. The 4th Unique value occuring gets assigned to the correct groups. As do the subsequent 5th and 6th unique values. The unique values are spread with Group 1 = 2, Group 2 = 3, Group 3 = 1. So 6 unique values occuring but it starts a 4th Group. Instead of filling Group 1 or Group 3. Can we move this to a private discussion?

Comment: You can do it through SO but you need 100 reputation.

Comment: @jonboy I again found a bug at line ```free = list(up.loc[ind_freed, "Index"])
        ``` plz try above edited code. Else you can start a chat room in tlk.io and send me link in this comment

Comment: Thanks @Dev Khadka. It was a tricky bit of code. It works well going up. Just a tiny issue when unqiue values occuring drops significantly. Say we need 5 groups at a period of time but we only need 3 a few periods later. It still distributes unique values across 5 Groups instead of the available amount of groups. You effort is more tha  enough though. Thankyou

Comment: @jonboy you're welcome, that is because when a place is assigned a group it takes same group until the place is finished (will not appear again). For the case you mentioned we need to rearrange group among available places when a place finishes. But caveat is that same place will be assigned different group on its life time.

Comment: It's quite brilliant. Yeh, I'm wrapping my head around it. The method I used to determine available groups isn't watertight so assigning places to groups shouldn't necessarily be the appropriate method. In saying that, how difficult would it be to rearrange places among available places when a group becomes unavailable? I like that place is assigned to a group for it's entirety. There just may have to be some manual manipulation when groups are unavailable. I essentially have no more than 5 groups available at any one time but the total groups available in total could be up tp 10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200268/discussion-between-dev-khadka-and-jonboy).